# Constructor overloading java

Tags: java, constructor, type-conversion, output, implicit-conversion

How does Java decide which constructor to call in below program?

```
public class Test   
{  
    Test(int a, int b)  
    {  
        System.out.println("a = "+a+" b = "+b);  
    }  
    Test(int a, float b)  
    {  
        System.out.println("a = "+a+" b = "+b);  
    }  
    public static void main (String args[])  
    {  
        byte a = 10;   
        byte b = 15;  
        Test test = new Test(a,b);  
    }  
}
```

The the first constructor taking second parameter as int is called, but if I remove first constructor, then the other constructor is called. In case both constructors are there, why the first one is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case both `byte` arguments are widened to int, and this is preferable to converting one argument to float.

In the second case there's no constructor taking two `int`s, so the only possible choice involves the conversion.

The language definition document contains an exhaustive discussion of constructor resolution.

Comment: does automatic conversion goes step by step, like convert byte to int and see if match is there and if not, convert byte to float?

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the language spec. There is no point in rewriting it here because there is already a canonical description readily accessible.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html